# Extracting ttf font ligature mappings

Tags: javascript, fonts, ligature

I have an existing [ttf font](https://github.com/jossef/material-design-icons-iconfont/blob/master/dist/fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf) where I wish to extract all Ligature mappings into this form:

```
{
    "calendar_today": "E935",
    "calendar_view_day": "E936",
    ...
}
```

I'm using [fontkit](https://github.com/foliojs/fontkit) with this script:

```js
const fontkit = require('fontkit');
let font = fontkit.openSync('./MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf');
let lookupList = font.GSUB.lookupList.toArray();
let lookupListIndexes = font.GSUB.featureList[0].feature.lookupListIndexes;

lookupListIndexes.forEach(index => {
    let subTable = lookupList[index].subTables[0];
    let ligatureSets = subTable.ligatureSets.toArray();

    ligatureSets.forEach(ligatureSet => {
        ligatureSet.forEach(ligature => {
            let character = font.stringsForGlyph(ligature.glyph)[0];
            let characterCode = character.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).toUpperCase();

            let ligatureText = ligature
                .components
                .map(x => font.stringsForGlyph(x)[0])
                .join('');

            console.log(`${ligatureText} -> ${characterCode}`);
        });
    });
});
```

However, I'm not getting the full Ligature names. output:

```
...
alendar_today -> E935
rop_portrait -> E3C5
ontact_phone -> E0CF
ontrol_point -> E3BA
hevron_right -> E5CC
...
```

What am I doing wrong? Judging by the analysis with FontForge, the font's Ligature names are not missing any characters.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted [here](https://github.com/foliojs/fontkit/issues/187#issuecomment-464363689), the first character is calculated according to a coverage range records.

first, calculate the leading characters

```
let leadingCharacters = [];
subTable.coverage.rangeRecords.forEach((coverage) => {
    for (let i = coverage.start; i <= coverage.end; i++) {
        let character = font.stringsForGlyph(i)[0];
        leadingCharacters.push(character);
    }
});
```

then, access these characters by the index of the subtable

```
let ligatureSets = subTable.ligatureSets.toArray();
ligatureSets.forEach((ligatureSet, ligatureSetIndex) => {

    let leadingCharacter = leadingCharacters[ligatureSetIndex];

    ligatureSet.forEach(ligature => {
        let character = font.stringsForGlyph(ligature.glyph)[0];
        let characterCode = character.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).toUpperCase();

        let ligatureText = ligature
            .components
            .map(x => font.stringsForGlyph(x)[0])
            .join('');

        ligatureText = leadingCharacter + ligatureText;

        console.log(`${ligatureText} -> ${characterCode}`);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code provided by Jossef Harush Kadouri above and it did not work.
Mb Fontkit changed the API, but several corrections fixed the script.

```
const getLigatures = (fontPath) => {
  const result = {};
  const font = fontkit.openSync(fontPath);

  const lookupList = font.GSUB.lookupList.toArray();
  const lookupListIndexes = font.GSUB.featureList[0].feature.lookupListIndexes;

  lookupListIndexes.forEach(index => {
    const subtables = lookupList[index].subTables;

    subtables.forEach(subTable => {
      const leadingCharacters = [];
      subTable.extension.coverage.rangeRecords.forEach(coverage => {
        for (let i = coverage.start; i <= coverage.end; i++) {
          let character = font.stringsForGlyph(i)[0];
          leadingCharacters.push(character);
        }
      });
      const ligatureSets = subTable.extension.ligatureSets.toArray();

      ligatureSets.forEach((ligatureSet, ligatureSetIndex) => {
        const leadingCharacter = leadingCharacters[ligatureSetIndex];

        ligatureSet.forEach(ligature => {
          const character = font.stringsForGlyph(ligature.glyph)[0];
          if (!character) return;

          const ligatureText =
            leadingCharacter +
            ligature.components.map(x => font.stringsForGlyph(x)[0]).join('');
          const code = character
            .charCodeAt(0)
            .toString(16)
            .toLowerCase();
          const iconName = ligatureText.toLowerCase();

          result[iconName] = code;
        });
      });
    });
  });

  return result;
};
```